# Linq Query return a Concat of Dates to String?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method `GetNotices()` that returns an `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.
Foreach Date in the collection I want to convert to a string and concatenate the string. I could do a Foreach loop surely. But why would I do that when I have the powers of LINQ! This is what I have tried right now.

```
bill.GetNotices().ToList().Concat(x => {return x.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " ";});
```

I've also tried...

```
bill.GetNotices().ToList().ForEach(x => {return x.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " ";});
```

Comment: `ForEach` is not LINQ. `ToList` is not needed. Take a look at [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`String.Join<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx)** - It accepts delimiter string and `IEnumerable<T>()`

```
var billList = bill.GetNotices().ToList();
var resultString = String.Join(",", billList.Select(d => d.ToString()));
```

EDIT* (for your solution):

```
var resultString = String.Join(" ", billList.Select(d => d.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")));
```

---

1. `Concat()` - is used to concatenate two seuences. So, here two lists.
2. `ForEach()` - is used to iterate on a sequence and usually used to set a value.

Comment: I removed the `bill.GetNotices().ToList()` piece as `.Join` accepts `IEnumerable<T>()`

Comment: Ohh, so yes. It would work without `.ToList()` too. And which is why I removed `.ToArray()` Great!

Comment: I think you mean `String.Join<T>()`, the variant without the generic, `String.Join()` is an instance method and requires a `string[]` as parameter. Although the link is valid.

Comment: @Igor, Yes I had linked the 'without generic' to the answer. I would edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: @Igor Visual studio is showing `string.Join()` accepts `(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values)` as one of its overloads. I am not specifically using the `String.Join<T>()` Method. Which is showing '(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)`

Comment: @ChrisClark, **[this is the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx)** for the overload your are using.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result=  string.Join(" ", bill.GetNotices().Select(date => date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")).ToArray());
```

---

- [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) - takes a separator and an array of strings (`string[]`), hence the call to `ToArray` later.
- You mentioned that `GetNotices()` already returns a `IEnumerable<DateTime>` instance so you can execute a select directly on that to convert the `DateTime` into a string formatted as you specified and then convert that result into a string array.